# How check gmail account's password using php

Tags: php, validation, gmail

I have one form with email and password field. When user enter password at a time i need to check that password is true or not as per entered gmail email id.

In short terms I need to check **Entered password** is same as **actual gmail account password** as per **entered email id**.

Comment: No no no no no. Don't do this, use Google's own oauth sign in.

Comment: What @Jon said. This is, frankly, a horrible and extremely dangerous idea.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's internal or external frankly. If you want to auth based on google account credentials, use oauth.

Comment: That made no sense, but either way, your current approach is foolish, insecure and dangerous. It doesn't matter what the application you're working on is.

Comment: @ShaileshChauhan you should listen to Jon

Comment: the problem is that you have no clue about what u want at all @ShaileshChauhan if you want us to be silent delete the post

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks fixed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got that using given script

```
    function check_email_password()
    {
        $mailbox_email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $mailbox_password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $mb = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',$mailbox_email,$mailbox_password) or die(json_encode(array('success'=>false,'massage'=>'Password is false.','error'=>imap_last_error())));
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'massage'=>'Password is true.'));
    }
```

Note => You must enable **IMAP Access** for gmail account

Answer (score -1):

You can never check or even ask for users to enter their Gmail password, it's illegal, however you can use the [Gmail Auth system](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) based on JWT token in order to provide Gmail auth on your website.

Comment: I don't need to implement login with google just i check username and password

Comment: well you just CAN'T

Comment: @ShaileshChauhan why would google allow a stranger an access to their usernames and passwords db?